# Maximum and minimum for $f(z)=z^m \Pi_n (1-z/a_n)$ and $g(z)=z^m \Pi_n(1-z/|a_n|)$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

Let me use the following notation:

**Notation.** For an entire function $f$ and $r>0$, let $M(r,f)$ and $m(r,f)$ denote $\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$ and $\min_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$, respectively.

**Problem.**(Ahlfors, Chap.5, Sec. 3.2. #2)
Assume that an entire function $f(z)$ has genus zero so that $f(z)=z^m \Pi_n (1-z/a_n)$. Compare $f(z)$ with $g(z)=z^m \Pi_n(1-z/|a_n|)$ and show that $M(r,f) \leq M(r,g)$ and that $m(r,f) \geq m(r,g)$ for all $r>0$.

How do I have to start? I really have no idea. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried proving this for finitely many zeros?

Comment: @Sean Nemetz No but if I can do this the finite case, then the general case should follow similarly, since we can usually handle infinite product as a finite product

Comment: Alright, try doing the problem with 1 zero ( not equal to $z=0$ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $M(r,f) \leq M(r,g)$, we can use the triangle inequality on each term: $$|1-\frac{z}{a_n}| \leq 1+ |\frac{z}{a_n}|=1+\frac{r}{|a_n|}$$ If we take $z=-r$, we see that $M(r,f) \leq g(-r) \leq M(r,g)$. Can you think of an argument for $m(r,f) \geq m(r,g)$?

Comment: Thanks I think this argument can be also applied to the infinite product case. By the way, shouldn't $g(-r)$ should be replaced with $|g(-r)|$?

Comment: $g(-r)$ just happens to be real and positive, but sure you can say that.